# How to remove specific subdirectories in .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Even after extensive research I was unable to resolve following redirection. I tried tons of examples, but with no luck.

From this URL:
http://www.example.com/store/product/name

I would like to get:
http://www.example.com/name

Problem is that the only known string is "store". Other strings "product" and "name" could contain letters, numbers and "-" or "_" characters.

I am testing it on live website and also on this tester: htaccess.madewithlove.be

One of the examples I used:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^store/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $2 [L,R=301]
```

This seems to work on above tester website, but not in real environment. I think there is something wrong with the regexp and second parameter is not properly returned or I am missing something else.

I should also mention that the website runs on Wordpress and in .htaccess file there is also following section created automatically by Wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you enter `http://www.example.com/name` in browser does it load everything fine?

Comment: Yes, it does load it fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rule like this i.e. `redirect` before internal WP rule:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^store/([^/]+)/([^/]+) $2 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```